# Best way to reduce consecutive NAs to single NA

Tags: r

I need to reduce the consecutive NA's in a vector to a single NA, without touching the other values.
So, for example, given a vector like this:

```
NA NA  8  7 NA NA NA NA NA  3  3 NA -1  4
```

what I need to get, is the following result:

```
NA  8  7 NA  3  3 NA -1  4
```

Currently, I'm using the following function:

```
reduceConsecutiveNA2One <- function(vect){
  enc <- rle(is.na(vect))

  # helper func
  tmpFun <- function(i){
    if(enc$values[i]){
      data.frame(L=c(enc$lengths[i]-1, 1), V=c(TRUE,FALSE))
    }else{
      data.frame(L=enc$lengths[i], V=enc$values[i])
    }
  }

  Df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,lapply(1:length(enc$lengths),FUN=tmpFun))

  return(vect[rep.int(!Df$V,Df$L)])
}
```

and it seems to work fine, but probably there's a simpler/faster way to accomplish this task.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NA NA NA NA...NA NA NA NA...hey hey hey..nevermind

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
x <- c(NA, NA,8,7,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, NA, -1,  4)

x[!(is.na(x) & diff(c(FALSE, is.na(x)))==0)]
# [1] NA  8  7 NA  3  3 NA -1  4

## It also works for length-one vectors
x <- NA
x[!(is.na(x) & diff(c(FALSE, is.na(x)))==0)]
# [1] NA
```

Comment: It could even be a bit shorter: `x[!is.na(x) | diff(c(FALSE, is.na(x)))]`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could be useful

```
x <- c(NA, NA,8,7,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, NA, -1,  4)
c(x[rowSums(is.na(embed(x,2)))!=2], x[length(x)])
[1] NA  8  7 NA  3  3 NA -1  4
```

If you want a function try:

```
myfun <- function(x){
  if(length(x)==1) {
    return(x)
  }
  else{
    return(c(x[rowSums(is.na(embed(x,2)))!=2], x[length(x)]))
  }
}

> myfun(x)
[1] NA  8  7 NA  3  3 NA -1  4
> y <- c(x, NA, NA, NA, 3)
> y
 [1] NA NA  8  7 NA NA NA NA NA  3  3 NA -1  4 NA NA NA  3
> myfun(y)
 [1] NA  8  7 NA  3  3 NA -1  4 NA  3
> myfun(NA)
[1] NA
> myfun(1)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Really smart. It just needs to check if the vector has one element only (because it crashes).

Comment: @digEmAll `myfun` now check for `length` and it now can handle vectors with length 1.

Answer (score 3):

A fun little exercise using `head` and `tail`:

```
merge.na <- function(x) c(head(x, 1), tail(x, -1)[!(is.na(tail(x, -1)) &
                                                    is.na(head(x, -1)))])
```

Comment: This is also very elegant and clever ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not as cool as the other responses but a different approach using `rle`:

```
x <- c(NA, NA,  8,  7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  3,  3, NA, -1,  4)
x[is.na(x)] <- 999
y <- rle(x)
y[[1]][y[[2]]==999] <- 1
y[[2]][y[[2]]==999] <- NA
rep(y[[2]], y[[1]])

#per Dason's Suggestion:
inverse.rle(y)
```

It is actually surprising to me the `rle` doesn't group NAs together.  It does this:

```
> rle(x)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:13] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
  values : num [1:13] NA NA 8 7 NA NA NA NA NA 3 ...
```

Hence the need to recode to 999

Comment: Yes, unfortunately rle doesn't recode NAs (it would be easier if it does). The problem is that I can't consider any value as out of range (not 999, not 99999 and so on...) and use it in place of NAs.

Comment: @Sven not sure if your comment is for my solution or the `rle` and `NA` thing.  My solution works with consecutive integers as the example I provide shows.  But alas it won't work for didEmAll's needs.  I mean you could convert this to character by adding a character value and then replace and convert back but it was already a less cool solution to begin with :)

Comment: Don't forget about `inverse.rle`.  It essentially just does what you have in the last line of code but is a little bit safer.

Comment: @Dason  Forget?  I never knew about it.  I added it to show its use.